# What is the fastest way to incease my athletics skills in Morrowind?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I have recently started playing Morrowind, and despite having Athletics as one of my minor skills, I still move very sluggishly, and also quite literally can't jump an inch of the ground.

Is there any way to boost this skill so I am not tip toeing all along Vvardenfell?

Comment: If you *literally* can't jump, you might be carrying too much.  One of the limiting factors on your jump height is your encumbrance.

Comment: @Mark no, because when I only had my prisoner clothes I still couldn't  jump

Comment: "[Speed](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Speed) is the governing Attribute for Athletics [...] It affects: How fast you move in the game world."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the Notes on the [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages - Morrowind:Athletics](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Athletics#Notes)

> You can quickly train Athletics with minimal effort by toggling on Autowalk while facing a wall. This will passively increase Athletics skill without your character accidentally walking into trouble. A more effective way to do this is to swim towards a wall; a well-suited place for this is the river running through Balmora.

---

> also can't jump quite literally an inch of the ground

this is actually your [Acrobatics](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Acrobatics) skill which is separate from Athletics

> The Acrobatics skill involves jumping, climbing, and avoiding damage from falls
>
> ...
>
> - With an extremely excessively high acrobatics skill it is possible to jump from one end of the map to the other.

a quick way to increase this skill is to jump while running up a slope. i tend to find the slopes for going up level on the outside of Vivec's Cantons are great places because each jump will help improve the skill no matter how high you jump, jumping up against a slope as you go up it mean you do lots of tiny jumps. i believe i've counted 10-20 jumps from one slope in the Foreign Quarter

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful response. I will try these techniques out later!

Comment: Just leave the game running through the night while walking/swimming in the wall. Does wonders.

Comment: This tactic works well. I literally just went into a corner and taped my joystick up. Now gaining skill levels.

Comment: You also gain more Acrobatics experience if you take falling damage.  However... don't kill yourself

Answer (score 1):

In the console (accessed by default using backtick, <kbd>`</kbd>) you can set your athletics (which influences speed) and acrobatics (which influences jump height) to a reasonable value between 1 and 999 like this:

```
player->setathletics 200
player->setacrobatics 200
```

This might be unpopular with some people, but you could think of it as avoiding mindless drudgery and wasting many hours of computing resources to get to a reasonable set of movement parameters.

Comment: And the question did ask for the fastest way, and this probably is the fastest way. :-)

Comment: Unless your on Xbox, where the console is not available.